# Showing that the integral of one equation yields another.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

> Background: The equations are derived from a Physics 2 Lab circuit that has a resistor and a capacitor
>
> > Problem: Show that the integral of **equation 5** yields **equation 2**.

I'm given:

$I(t) = \frac{Ve^{-t/RC}}{R}$ ***Equation 5***

$V - \frac{dq}{dt} R - \frac{q}{c} = 0$ ***Equation 2***

> My attempt:

I'm just a bit confused on if I should be solving for the integral with respects to time or not. What I was thinking was something like this:

$\int \frac{Ve^{-t/RC}}{R} \frac{dq}{dt}$

though I am not entirely sure. The multiple variables are causing slight confusion for me. Any advice or reassurance would be great.

Comment: A question: what does $q$ represent?, and $C$? The rest of the variables are shared between them.

Comment: I believe $q$ represents charge and $C$ represents capacitance

Comment: Basically just constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I(t) = \frac{Ve^{-t/RC}}{R}$$
The desired equation does not contain $t$ explicitly except in $\frac{dq}{dt}$, but it does contain $q$. This suggests us to write,
$$\tag1I(t)=\frac{dq}{dt}=\frac{Ve^{-t/RC}}{R}$$
Now, integrate with respect to $t$,
$$\int_{0}^q\frac{dq}{dt}dt=\int_{0}^t\frac{Ve^{-t/RC}}{R}dt$$
$$q=\left[\frac{Ve^{-t/RC}}{R}(-RC)\right]_0^t=\frac{Ve^{-t/RC}}{R}(-RC)+CV$$
$$q={CV(1-e^{-t/RC})}$$
Thus,
$$\frac qC=V(1-e^{-t/RC})$$
$$\tag2V-\frac qC=Ve^{-t/RC}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get the desired result.

Comment: Oh okay this makes complete sense. I actually did solve dq/dt in a problem prior to this. Thank you.